# Need examples/suggestions for search and add if not exists feature

Tags: forms, search, edit

We are implementing a functionality in our iPhone app.
The functionality is that -
 - User searches for his/her school or college
 - If the school/college exists in our database we show them

This can be done by showing a simple table and a search bar on top of it.

Now, we need to enhance that functionality in a such a way that - if the school/college is not listed in our database, we want to give the user the ability to add his/her school.

Can you suggest any examples of such UX? or any suggestions on how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can add a button on the bottom of the search result, so that if the college or school is not available the user can add it by directly clicking the "Add missing School/College" button. It would be a better user experience in my perspective.

Hope this helps..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of showing table for all the colleges or schools present in the database, show it with list interface and keep search bar on top of list and make it fix to the screen so when user scrolls the list it wouldn't be scrolled. So anytime user can search the college and give "others" as last item in list. If user clicks on that then just give popup to enter their college/school name. It's very simple approach so don't get confused.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH4Vg6.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>